# Google Groups: "Unable to load pending messages for moderation". Where to report this bug?

Tags: google-groups

Since 3 days, every time I open the [message moderation page of the Google Group I administrate](http://groups.google.com/group/anki-android/pendmsg), I can see this message:

```
Unable to load pending messages for moderation
```

[image: Unable to load pending messages for moderation]

Usually this page would list the messages from new users that are awaiting approval.
The window title tells me that there are 15 messages awaiting, and the number keeps growing, but I can not moderate.

Using the mobile version to access http://groups.google.com/group/anki-android/pendmsg is worse: it just shows the Google Groups homepage.

The error message is unknown by Google Search, so I guess few groups have seen this problem.
Another moderator of the group told me he has the same problem, though.

**QUESTION:** How should I report this to Google?
I could not find a [help forum](http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=portal_groups.cs) nor an issue tracker, nor a feedback form.

Comment: Switching back to the old Google Groups format solves the problem momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report to Google by clicking on the "settings" icon on the top right and from the drop down menu selecting the option "Report an issue about Google Groups". I have the same problem and already did that. Hopefully the more people doing the same the more chances we will have to be able to get a reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I did report "Unable to load pending messages for moderation" to Google Report an issue about Google Groups. No response is heard. For the time being, I go to *Manage* → *Settings* → *Moderation* and uncheck the **Moderate all messages to the Group** and leave Moderate messages from new members of the group. This way, I get new incoming message from members.

Answer (score 0):

I had to not only switch to the old Google Groups format but also had to click on the pending message and view the whole thing before it would let me allow the post.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to allow the messages is to ask the moderator of the group just to reply the confirmation message instead of clicking on the link to moderate.